# Nginx rewrite but Facebook doesn't like it

Tags: facebook, url, nginx, url-rewriting, adsense

Before using Nginx, with Apache when I was rewriting an url, I could share a page on Facebook and it puts the correct url in the sharer.

Now, with Nginx, when I share https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://beautifulurl.com/page25 Facebook catchs only http://beautifulurl.com so I lose the full page url.

Also with AdSense I've problems(in some pages it doesn't show ads) and also with Google+ sharer.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The display link of the share will always show the top level domain, when you click the shared link it will follow the URI that you've given to sharer.php

Comment: Ok, but title and description? :(

Answer (score 0):

have you tried replacing the punctuation:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fbeautifulurl.com%2Fpage25
```